# Datalist return option's data-value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to have an onChange function to return the "option's data-value" only when an option is selected in the datalist.

So How can i return the data-value which is the hidden value of the selected option.

```
  const [country, setCountry] = useState();
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  <input
    list="dropdown__countries"
    className="header__dropbtn"
    placeholder="Search Country"
    onChange={setCountry(event.target.value)}
  />
  <datalist id="dropdown__countries">
    {props.countries.map((country) => (
      <option data-value={country.value} value={country.name} />
    ))}
  </datalist>
```

The onChange in this snippet only returns the input data.. Which isn't what i'm trying to do, I don't want the input data instead i want the the (data-value of the selected option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the `country` with the given current `value`.

```js
function DataList(props) {
  const [countryValue, setCountryValue] = useState();

  function onChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;

    // find the country with the current selected value
    const country = props.countries.find((c) => c.name === value);

    if (country !== undefined) {
      // use selected country object here

      setCountryValue(country.value);
      console.log(country.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        list="dropdown__countries"
        className="header__dropbtn"
        placeholder="Search Country"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <datalist id="dropdown__countries">
        {props.countries.map((country) => (
          <option
            key={country.value}
            data-value={country.value}
            value={country.name}
          />
        ))}
      </datalist>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit vigorous-meadow-pkhyw]

Comment: Thankyou for your response I appreciate it! But i edited my question can you please reread it maybe it wasn't clear

Comment: Thankyou dude appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You made the mistake of passing the value of the setCountry() function call instead of a function.

Do this instead:

```
 const [country, setCountry] = useState();
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  <input
    list="dropdown__countries"
    className="header__dropbtn"
    placeholder="Search Country"
    onChange={(event)=>setCountry(event.target.value)}
  />
  <datalist id="dropdown__countries">
    {props.countries.map((country) => (
      <option data-value={country.value} value={country.name} />
    ))}
  </datalist>
```